# HTML5 Philosophy: Omission of certain semantic elements?

Tags: html

I am wondering if this applies.

Examples:

1. `main` tag

   The HTML5 specification says:

   > The main element represents the main content section of the body of a
   >   document or application. The main content section **consists of content
   >   that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a
   >   document** or central functionality of an application.

   Does this, therefore, imply that:

   If the only content that lives within your page is the `main` content and only the main content, you should exclude the tag since there is nothing to relate it to but itself?
2. `section` tag

   The HTML5 specification says:

   > The section element represents a generic section of a document or
   >   application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
   >   content.

   If the only content that lives within your page is within a `section`, then does that mean that your page should not be sectioned, but rather be a single element, and therefore you should not use a `section` tag?

My thoughts:

I think the `main` tag should be omitted in the case provided, however, the section tag should be required since a page can be sectioned off into a single section. The word section can be used to describe a single part of a whole regardless of whether that part is the only one of the whole.

The Layout I was thinking about:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    ...
  body
    header
    main
      section
    nav
    footer
```

becomes:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    ...
  body
    header
    section
    nav
    footer
```

Comment: I would read it differently - the central topic of a document is what that *specific page / URI is for*. So if its an About page, and all you have is an content about your site, wrapping it in `main` lets everyone know that content addresses the About directly. Also if you start dropping tags, how would you distinguish between a page that contains 1 section vs. a page that contains 1 main if you removed both tags. Also practically, having tags is easier for styling. Its better to put tags and style `main` than to style `main` and first-child of body with n other exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the main tag should be omitted in the case provided, however,
>   the section tag should be required since a page can be sectioned off
>   into a single section.

There was a similar suggestion in an earlier candidate recommendation (see https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/common-idioms.html#the-main-part-of-the-content) which recommended implicit marking of the main content OR having `body` mark up the main content with elements (like `header`, `nav`, `footer`) exclude the other (non `main` content) bits (as you suggested).

**BUT**, this section was later dropped (see https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Feb/0037.html or just search for *Re: Week 4/5: Staged WHATWG patches for HTML5.1 / HTML5.0 CR* in the *public-html* list at https://www.w3.org/Search/Mail/Public/advanced_search). To quote

> I do not think this section should be included, as it states that
>   there is not a dedicated element for marking up the main part of the
>   content of a page.This contradicts the definition of main in HTML 5.1

---

Additionally, if you look at https://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/User:Sfaulkne/main-usecases#Introduction, there are use cases where not using a `main` tag would necessitate an alternative (like `role="main"` for ARIA or some structure based CSS for styling), so IMO it would be preferable to have the `main` tag even if you were just going by the use cases.

Note - it's still recommended that you use `role="main"` even if you the `main` tag (until all browsers automatically map the `main` element to `role="main"`)

---

Under the `main` tag, you could have a `section` tag if you want to indicate that it forms part of something else (see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#article-or-section?)

And on a related note, while you can markup content with an `article` tag when the main content of the page (excluding all the extra bits) is self contained, the spec says that it is technically redundant (see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element). To quote

> ...the content should be marked up with a main element and the content
>   may also be marked with an article, but it is technically redundant in
>   this case (since it's self-evident that the page is a single
>   composition, as it is a single document).

---

To summarize

1. You need the `main` tag.
2. You don't need the `section` tag unles you want to indicate that it forms part of something else.